# Как сделать автозапуск screen в Debian

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen

Создал скрипт

`jabber.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
cd  /var/www/nancydemo
mono JabberMatrixConsole.exe
```

На данный момент я его запускаю через `screen`. Но хотелось бы пихнуть это дело в автозапуск, дабы постоянно не делать этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файл `/etc/rc.local` перед строкой `exit 0` добавьте

```
screen -d -m -S jabber /полный/путь/jabber.sh
```

Параметр `-S jabber` не обязательный, он задает имя консоли, что бы потом к ней было легче подключаться по имени, а не по id процесса `screen -D jabber`